# Magento 1.9 Share cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I don't know if I can post this here, to answer questions, I wanted to do this, but I don't know where to start, if anyone can help, I am very grateful

hello friends, is it possible to share a cart? I have a customer who needs to share a cart with other people, his idea would be to set up a cart and send the link to the person to finalize the purchase, he is doing this to help older people to buy online easily

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below extension for share cart functionality.

https://redchamps.com/share-shopping-cart-magento-1-extension.html

Comment: I have another affiliate module, and I needed to add this function to it, buying this module would not solve, do you do that kind of work?